# How to embed an ActiveX control to WPF (desktop)

Tags: .net, wpf, activex

How to embed an ActiveX control to WPF (desktop)? Why I cannot find the control in the toolbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2007/05/07/tip-trick-embedding-activex-in-wpf-with-windowsformshost-video-demo.aspx

Comment: @DavidePiras Thanks for your link. So embed the ActiveX control to a Windows Form first is the only way to do this, right?